# Replacing switch by BinaryOperator

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface, binary-operators

I'm trying to replace the common switch for arithmetical operations by `BinaryOperator` functional interface.

The base method is:

```
private static int computeOne(int res, String operand, String operation) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(operand);

    switch (operation) {
        case "+":
            res += number;
            break;
        case "-":
            res -= number;
            break;
        case "*":
            res *= number;
            break;
        case "/":
            res = (number != 0 ? res / number : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            break;
        default:
            res = 0;
            System.out.println("unknown operation");
    }

    return res;
}
```

As I understand it's nesessary to write something like:

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> action = (a,b) -> computeExpression(a + operation + b);
action.apply(res, operand);
```

But I don't understand how to avoid `switch` in `computeExpression` that would be the same as `computeOne`.

Comment: I have to admit, that I don't understand the question, even if there is an accepted answer. computeExpression seems only vaguely related to ComputeOne, operand and operation are Strings for unclear reasons. What is the restriction (operation being a variable? Of type String?), what is the goal? Converting a String to Int doesn't seem to be the problem, so why is it that way? `a + operation + b` looks like it would result in "42*14". Why merge them, when you later need to split them?

Comment: @userunknown, I think he meant `computeExpression(a, operation, b)` to make it similar to the signature of `computeOne`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` for each arithmetic operation:

```
// a = operand 1
// b = operand 2
(a, b) -> a * b;
(a, b) -> a + b;
(a, b) -> a / b;
(a, b) -> a - b;
```

Then you can apply one passing 2 arguments:

```
// result = operation.apply(a, b);
int result = ((BinaryOperator<Integer>) ((a, b) -> a * b)).apply(2, 2);
```

I would use an enum to enumerate these operations:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(computeOne(4, "2", "/"));  // 2
         System.out.println(computeOne(4, "2", "*"));  // 8
         System.out.println(computeOne(4, "2", "-"));  // 2
         System.out.println(computeOne(4, "2", "+"));  // 6
    }

    private static int computeOne(int res, String operand, String operation) {
        return Operation.getOperationBySymbol(operation)
                        .getBinaryOperator()
                        .apply(res, Integer.parseInt(operand));
    }

    private enum Operation {
        // operation = symbol, action
        MULTIPLICATION("*", (a, b) -> a * b),
        ADDITION("+", (a, b) -> a + b),
        SUBTRACTION("-", (a, b) -> a - b),
        DIVISION("/", (a, b) -> a / b);

        private final BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator;
        private final String symbol;

        Operation(String symbol, BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.binaryOperator = binaryOperator;
        }

        public BinaryOperator<Integer> getBinaryOperator() {
            return binaryOperator;
        }

        public String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }

        public static Operation getOperationBySymbol(String symbol) {
            for (Operation operation : values()) {
                if (operation.getSymbol().equals(symbol)) {
                    return operation;
                }
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown symbol: " + symbol);
        }
    }

}
```

You also can "simplify" it with a `BiFunction<BinaryOperator<?>, Pair<?, ?>, ?>`:

```
// BiFunction<Operator, Operands, Result>
// Operator = BinaryOperator<?>
// Operands = Pair<?, ?>
BiFunction<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Pair<Integer, Integer>, Integer> f = 
    (operator, operands) -> 
        operator.apply(operands.getKey(), operands.getValue());

f.apply((a, b) -> a + b, new Pair<>(2, 2)); // 4
```

Answer (score 3):

The arithmetical operator cannot be a variable.
By using a functional interface or without as in your actual code, you would have the same constraint : transform the `String` operator to an arithmetical operator.

Besides, actually in `computeOne()` you accept an `int` and two `String`s as parameter and you returns an `int`.
`BinaryOperator<Integer>` accepts two `Integer` and return an `Integer`.
So it it not compatible.
You would need a `TriFunction` but it doesn't exist.
Either create your own functional interface such as `TriFunction<T,U,V,R>` 
or reduce the number of parameter passed to your function.

Here is an example using an enum `Operator` combined with `BiFunction` that performs the same thing as your actual method.
Note that as the operator is now represented by the enum `Operator` responsible to execute the function, the function needs only two parameters now : the `Integer` and the `String` that you convert into an `int`.
So `BiFunction<Integer, String, Integer>` is fine.

```
public enum Operator{
    ADD("+", (a,b) -> a + Integer.parseInt(b)), 
    SUBSTRACT("-", (a,b) -> a - Integer.parseInt(b)),
    MULTIPLY("*", (a,b) -> a * Integer.parseInt(b)),
    //       ...
    DEFAULT("", (a,b) -> 0);

    public BiFunction<Integer, String, Integer> function;
    private String symbol;

    Operator(String symbol, BiFunction<Integer, String, Integer> function){
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.function = function;
    }

    public int compute(int actualValue, String operand){
        return function.apply(actualValue, operand);
    }

    public static Operator of(String symbol) {
        for (Operator value : values()) {
            if (symbol.equals(value.symbol)) {
                return value;
            }
        }

        return Operator.DEFAULT;
    }

}
```

You could create so an operation such as :

```
int res = 10;
String operand = "15";
String symbol = "+";
res = Operator.of(symbol).compute(res, operand);
```